# how to update name with variable in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have dummy template of `package.json` . I want to copy dummy package.json inside some folder **(Application name folder)** and update the **name**  from from package.json . can we do this in node js.

here is my source **package.json** file

```
{
  "name":"$name"
}
```

I tried like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

let appName = prompt('what is application name..?');
if(!appName){
    appName='temp'
}

console.log(`Application name is ${appName}`);

if (!fs.existsSync(`${appName}`)){
    fs.mkdirSync(`${appName}`);
}

fs.copyFile('./source/package.json', `${appName}/package.json`, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```

when I run `node index.js` . it ask "application name" user enter application name let say example (abc). It create a folder `abc` and put package.json file which is working fine.

**Now issue is I want the content of package.json is**

```
{
  "name":"abc"
}
```

can we replace the name variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `./abc/package.json` and its contents look like this:

```json
{
  "name": "$name",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

If you want to modify just the `name` field, you'll have to:

1. read the package data as JSON text
2. parse it as an object
3. modify the `name` property to your desired value
4. write it back to the file

A minimal example of doing that in a script might look like this:

`./rename.mjs`:

```js
import {readFile, writeFile} from 'node:fs/promises';

const pkgPath = './abc/package.json';
const textEncoding = {encoding: 'utf-8'};

const json = await readFile(pkgPath, textEncoding);

const pkgData = JSON.parse(json);

pkgData.name = 'abc';

const prettyJson = JSON.stringify(pkgData, null, 2);

await writeFile(pkgPath, prettyJson, textEncoding);
```

After you run it:

```
node rename.mjs
```

The package contents will be updated:

```json
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.1.0"
}
```

Ref:

- [`fsPromises.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options)
- [`fsPromises.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html#fspromiseswritefilefile-data-options)